# Craftsman Bolt-Out and similar tools

Tags: tools, stuck-bolt

I've seen Craftsman Bolt-Out mentioned in several questions/threads about removing stuck or rounded-off bolts, a problem I've run into many times. There's no particular problem I'm looking to solve right now, but it's something I might like to buy and have on hand for the next time I hit such a problem. But first I'd like to know if anybody has experience with this tool, particularly:

- Does it work often?
- How does it work?
- How do you identify which stuck-bolt situations it's likely to work for?

Comment: Tools like this can really help in the right circumstances but they aren't magic spells: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3742/57

Comment: Also keep in mind that the material they're made of is most likely harder than anything else you have in your garage and that includes your drills...

Answer (score 2):

These work when the head of the bolt has the corners rounded-off, usually from a wrench slipping. If the head is broken off and completely gone, they are not an option.

Generally they work best if you pound the bolt-out tool onto the damaged head with a hammer. So obviously it's best when there is room to swing a hammer at the bolt head. Easier with bolts that have a lower grade and softer metal.

Another option - if you have a welder - is to weld another piece of metal on the damaged bolt head and use that to turn the bolt out.

Comment: The welding part also puts a fair amount of focused heat onto the bolt, helping break it free.  But even a cheap welder costs a lot more than a set of bolt extractors and a Mapp gas torch. :D